# Set opacity to parent but not to child

Tags: css, opacity

I would like to set opacity to a parent div but not 1 particular child div.
So i have a html code like:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://url.jpg)
}
#main {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
#slider {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="slider">
    </div>
    <div id="content-wrapper">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Obviously this won't work. The whole #main div is now transparant to the background div. That is what i want but not the #slider div. For some reason, when only setting `opacity` to the #content-wrapper, nothing happens at all.
Any ideas?

Edit:
I can't use an rgba color, since i would like the background image to come through. Could you explain why adding opacity to #content-wrapper is not working?

Comment: If `background` is solid colored, So its better to use `rgba(0,0,0,.5)` (color as per your requirement) instead of `opacity`

Comment: Hi, I can't use an rgba color, since i would like the background image to come through. Could you explain why adding opacity to #content-wrapper is not working?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe with rgba or hsla color code can help

```
#someParent {

background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

}
```

Comment: Hi, I can't use an rgba color, since i would like the background image to come through. Could you explain why adding opacity to #content-wrapper is not working?